# Youtube Data API - How to get my private and unlisted videos

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Last year I was able to retrieve videos of all statuses (upon authenticating via OAuth) via [Playlistitems > list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) specifying the playlist containing all uploads.

As of today, the same code only gives me public uploads:

```
import os
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"]

def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    client_secrets_file = "CLIENT_SECRETS.json"

    # Get credentials and create an API client
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

    request = youtube.playlistItems().list(part="snippet", maxResults=50, playlistId="__PLAYLIST__ID")    
    response = request.execute()
    total = response['pageInfo']['totalResults']
    print("total number of videos is " + str(total));
    exit();

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am aware that others have asked this question but they are either really old posts or not answered comprehensively.

The only other possibile method seems to be [Search > list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) specifying the channel ID but this too only returned public videos despite authenticating via OAuth:

```
import os
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"]

def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    client_secrets_file = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_FILE.json"

    # Get credentials and create an API client
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

    request = youtube.search().list(
        part="snippet",
        channelId="___CHANNEL__ID___",
        type="video"
    )
    response = request.execute()

    print(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The documentation [claims](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) that setting the [`forMine`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#forMine) parameter:

> [...] can only be used in a properly [authorized request](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication). The `forMine` parameter restricts the search to only retrieve videos owned by the authenticated user. If you set this parameter to `true`, then the `type` parameter's value must also be set to `video`.

However, this resulted in an invalid request when I included `forMine` set to `true`.

Any advice on how to **currently** get private / unlisted YouTube video data would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you had any success with this? I'm having the same questions and only finding old solutions

Answer (score 1):

I would [not rely much](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169463520#comment4) on `totalResults`; this property is not reliable by its very specification (the emphasis below is mine):

> [**pageInfo.totalResults**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#pageInfo.totalResults) (integer)
>
> The total number of results in the result set. *Please note that the value is an approximation and may not represent an exact value.* In addition, the maximum value is 1,000,000.
>
> You should not use this value to create pagination links. Instead, use the `nextPageToken` and `prevPageToken` property values to determine whether to show pagination links.

If only needing the *number of items* of a given playlist, identified by its ID `PLAYLIST_ID`, I'd recommend querying the [`Playlists.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list) API endpoint with `id=PLAYLIST_ID` and looking for the property [`contentDetails.itemCount`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists#contentDetails.itemCount).

But, otherwise, if upon paginating (using the [`PlaylistItems.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) endpoint), the API wouldn't provide you all the private and unlisted videos (assuming that you passed on to the endpoint a valid access token), then most likely that's a bug of the API that [needs to be reported](https://issuetracker.google.com/).

Also, do note that, according to [YouTube's staff](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/166292064#comment2), there's an upper 20000 limit set *by design* for the number of items returned via `PlaylistItems.list` endpoint (nota bene: the design itself changes over time: as far as I know, not long ago this limit did not existed).

Comment: This answer does not answer the question. Is it even related to the question? Its like random information about the YouTube API that has nothing to do with permissions or private or unlisted videos.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the "Uploads" playlist. Use "mine=True".

```
youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build('youtube', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
r = youtube.channels().list(
    part='contentDetails',
    mine=True).execute()
uploads_playlist_id = r['items'][0]['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads']
```

Next, you can get all videos in this playlist

```
r = youtube.playlistItems().list(playlistId=uploads_playlist_id, 
part=snippet, maxResults=50).execute()
for item in r['items']:
    #...
```